# Immutable data structures in F#

Tags: f#, stack, immutability

I am trying to implement a very trivial stack in **F#** using its built-in generic type. Coming from the imperative paradigm it can sometimes be hard to imagine how to *avoid* mutability.

What I have so far is a simple data structure with a **push** and **pop** operator:

```
type Stack<'a> =
    | Empty
    | S of 'a list
with
member L.Push x =
    match L with
    | Empty | S ([]) -> S ([x])
    | S (V) ->  S (x :: V)
member L.Pop = 
    match L with
    | Empty | S ([]) -> failwith "Error: Stack is empty"
    | S (v::_) -> v
end
```

My idea was to make the Stack hold an `S of 'a list` where we modify the list with the cons `::` operator to not mutate the list `S`, but to replace it with `S'`. As of now, the stack can at most have one element, and it doesn't grow when pushing elements to it – likewise doesn't shrink when popped.

Can anyone give me a hint on how rewrite the structure/think about it differently?

Thank you!

Comment: There's a very similar implementation of an immutable stack on [F# Snippets](http://www.fssnip.net/er/title/Implementation-of-Immutable-Stack) - can understand if you don't want the answer straight up given to you though :)

Comment: Why can it only contain 1 value? It looks like `(Empty).Push(1).Push(2)` will return a stack with 2 elements in? Please add the code you're using to manipulate the stack. You will need to change your `Pop` method to return a pair containing the popped elements and new stack however.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in a more functional way by simply having a list act as the stack. Instead of methods you can make `push` and `pop` be functions instead.

```
// Returns the new stack
let push item stack = item :: stack

// Returns (item, newStack) tuple or throws if stack is empty
let pop stack =
    match stack with
    | [] -> failwith "Stack is empty"
    | item :: newStack -> item, newStack


// Example usage

let stack = []

let populatedStack = push "hello" stack
// populatedStack = ["hello"]

let item, emptiedStack = pop populatedStack
// item = "hello"
// emptiedStack = []
```

Comment: Although this works you haven't really abstracted away the implementation of the stack here.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in immutable list is already a valid Stack structure. The Push Operation is `::` and you get the last item with Pattern Matching like `let (first,rest) = list`

If you want to create a Stack from Scratch. Here are some implementations.

1)
a) a stack is either empty
b) or a value and a reference to the previous Stack.

```
type Stack<'a> =
    | Empty
    | Value of 'a * Stack<'a>

module Stack =
    let isEmpty = function
        | Empty   -> true
        | Value _ -> false
    let empty = Empty
    let push x stack = Value (x, stack) 
    let pop (Value (x, stack)) = x, stack


let stk =
    Stack.empty
    |> Stack.push 1
    |> Stack.push 2
    |> Stack.push 3

let rec loop stack =
    if   Stack.isEmpty stack
    then ()
    else
        let first, rest = Stack.pop stack
        printfn "First: %d" first
        loop rest

loop stk
```

You also could choose a record as the underlying data-structure.

```
type Stack<'a> = {
    Value: 'a option
    Next:  Stack<'a> option
}
```

This way, a Stack with three elements looks like.

```
{Value=Some 3; Next=
    {Value=Some 2; Next=
        {Value=Some 1; Next=
            {Value=None; Next=None}}}}
```

You also could choose a class with a `value` and `next` field and use `null` for the last element.

The important thing is how to work with those structures. The way to work with immutable data-structures is by using recursive functions instead of looping.

Creating a tail-recursive function that visits each element and executes a function on every element is the `fold` function, comparable to a `forEach`.